# Textbox1.Attribute.Add() for two different attributes in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am willing to know that,

Do there will be any issues if we use to different attributes for the same control?

For e.g.:
On Page_Load():

```
txtI.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) { __doPostBack('" + btnAdd1.UniqueID + "',''); return false; } else { ClearErrorText(); }");

txtI.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "javascript:ClearErrorText();");
```

Do this will make any problem in each other main functionality?

Comment: It won't cause any issue.You can add multiple events to the same control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely fine & there would not be any issue with this. It will finally render in the browser as follows:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
__doPostBack('btnAdd1ID',''); return false; } else { ClearErrorText(); }"
onfocus="javascript:ClearErrorText();" />
```

You can refer this tutorial further:

http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2009/01/29/adding-javascript-click-events-programmatically-in-code-behind-using-attributes-add.aspx